# Proving a sequence is split exact using Nakayama's lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $R=\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty}R_i$ be a graded ring with $R_0$ a field and let $M=\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty}M_i$ be a finitely generated graded module. Let $I \subseteq R$ be the homogeneous maximal ideal generated by the homogeneous elements of strictly positive degree.

I'm trying to prove that the following exact sequence splits:

$$0 \to IM \overset{i}{\to} M \overset{\pi}{\to} M/IM \to 0$$

where $i$ is the identity and $\pi$ is the projection.

$\textbf{My attempt}$:

By Nakayama's lemma for graded modules, if $\pi(x_1),...,\pi(x_k)$ generate $M/IM$ as an $R_0$ vector space, the representatives $x_1,...,x_k$ generate $M$ as an $R$-module. Hence we have an $R$-linear map
$$p: M/IM \to M$$
given by $p(\pi(x_i))=x_i$ such that $\pi p$ is the identity on $M/IM$, and so the sequence splits. Note this is well-defined due to our choice $x_i$ of representatives for the $\pi(x_i)$.

Now by the splitting lemma, this tells us that $M \cong IM \oplus M/IM$. This is what makes me doubt the claim. For any $r\in I$ and $v \in M/IM$, $rv=0$, so if $M$ happens to be a free module then for $(0,m) \in IM \oplus M/IM$ we have $$r(0,m)=(0,0),$$
but this shouldn't be, right? Where is the hole in my argument?

The source I'm using for the graded version of Nakayama's lemma is

http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W07/L01.29.pdf

Comment: I'm pretty sure this all makes sense actually if we consider all the modules as vector spaces over $R_0$

Comment: What if $M=R$? Then $I$ should be a direct summand of $R$ and if $R$ is a noetherian domain (which is not a field) this is impossible.

Comment: While I admit this isn't what I said in my question, the ideal $I$ wouldn't be a direct summand of $R$ as a module over $R$, though it would as a vector space over $R_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake shows up from the very beginning: the map $p$ you define is not a homomorphism of $R$-modules. The images of $x_i$'s form an $R/I$-basis in $M/IM$, while $M$ is only an $R$-module.

Comment: Yeah I realize it's not well-defined as a homomorphism of $R$-modules. What if we consider $M$ and $M/IM$ as vector spaces over $R_0$? In which case the sequence is a sequence of $R_0$ modules, not $R$-modules. Then mapping back into $M$ from $M/IM$ is a well-defined $R_0$-linear homomorphism

Comment: Does the problem become trivial at that point? I know every exact sequence of vector spaces splits, though I'm not sure it applies to infinite dimensional ones

Comment: @leibnewtz The splitting property holds for vector space without regard of the dimension. It also holds for free modules, and more generally for projective modules.

Comment: Neat, thanks! It turns out all I needed was for the short exact sequence to split for the modules as vector spaces over $R_0$, so that's perfect